# Re-Scaling Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

when i draw hline which is far away from current price region it shrinks chart (re scale) to show all the lines.

Is there any way i can keep all those hlines but not scaling/ squeezing my chart to show them all unless i am in that price area. or is there any function other than hline to help me fix this? Below is code i am using right now.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

hline(250000)
hline(150000)
hline(50000)
hline(5000)
hline(25000)
hline(75000)
```

Comment: Well, one way is to disable auto scaling. Or do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: i want it to be in code itself. see if you use this code it will mark lines as intended, but it will scale chart to show all lines. So i want chart to stay same but lines stay plotted as and when price reaches there we know our lines,I hope i am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can access this options on price scale by right clicking " Scale price Chart Only" option works and does not re scales chart after adding indicator.